# Define proper width in csv generated by sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

When i send mail with a csv attachment using sp_send_dbmail, columns are overlapped in file as shown in below

[image]

Is there any way to set proper width to columns like this.

[image]

Query i have used is

```
CREATE TABLE ##sample
(
header1 varchar(50),
header2 varchar(50),
header3 varchar(50),
)

INSERT ##sample VALUES ('Samlpe text Samlpe text','Samlpe text Samlpe text','Samlpe text Samlpe text')

INSERT ##sample VALUES ('Samlpe text Samlpe text','Samlpe text Samlpe text','Samlpe text Samlpe text')
DECLARE @column1name varchar(50),
@qry VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @qry =
('set nocount on; 
SELECT ''header1'', ''header2'', ''header3''
UNION ALL
SELECT  header1,header2,header3
FROM ##sample')

DECLARE
    @tab char(2) = CHAR(9)

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Mail Profile', 
@query = @qry,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Report.csv',
@query_result_separator=@tab,
@query_result_width =32767,
@query_result_no_padding=1,
@body = 'Empty',
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'raju.vadnala@gmail.com', 
@subject = 'Empty',
@query_result_header=0


drop table ##sample
```

Comment: You can't do it. csv has no with for column.

Comment: Is there any other work around ?

Comment: When i use xls format and opens the file, it says the fie format and extension of 'Report.xls' don't mactch. The file could be corrupted or unsafe

Comment: You use xls format or only change the extention?

Comment: @query_attachment_filename = 'report.xls'

Comment: you only Change the file extention. the Content is the same a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

No, csv file didn't have any format in it, your best bet is to use xls or ods format

Comment: When i use xls format and opens the file, it says the fie format and extension of 'Report.xls' don't mactch. The file could be corrupted or unsafe........